# How to import Delta Lake module in Zeppelin notebook and pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-zeppelin, delta-lake

I am trying to use Delta Lake in a Zeppelin notebook with pyspark and seems it cannot import the module successfully. e.g.

```
%pyspark
from delta.tables import *
```

It fails with the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'delta'

However, there is no problem to save/read the data frame using `delta` format. And the module can be loaded successfully if using scala spark `%spark`

Is there any way to use Delta Lake in Zeppelin and pyspark?

Answer (score 4):

Finally managed to load it on zeppelin pyspark. Have to explicitly include the jar file

```
%pyspark
sc.addPyFile("**LOCATION_OF_DELTA_LAKE_JAR_FILE**")
from delta.tables import *
```