# Module not found error when importing Pyspark Delta Lake module

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

I'm running Pyspark with delta lake but when I try to import the delta module I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'delta'`. This is on a machine without an internet connection so I had to download the delta-core jar manually from [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.delta/delta-core_2.11/0.6.1) and place it into the `%SPARK_HOME%/jars` folder.

My program works without any issues and I'm able to write and read from delta lake so I'm happy I've got the correct jar. But when I try and import the delta module `from delta.tables import *` I get the error.

For information my code is:

```
import os
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType, FloatType, StructType, StructField
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name
from Constants import Constants

if __name__ == "__main__":
    constants = Constants()
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]")\
                                .appName("Delta Lake Testing")\
                                .getOrCreate()

    # have to start spark session before importing: https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html#python
    from delta.tables import *

    # set logging level to limit output
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
    # push additional python files to the worker nodes
    base_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    spark.sparkContext.addPyFile(os.path.join(base_path, 'Constants.py'))

    # start pipeline
    schema = StructType([StructField("Timestamp", TimestampType(), False),\
                        StructField("ParamOne", FloatType(), False),\
                        StructField("ParamTwo", FloatType(), False),\
                        StructField("ParamThree", FloatType(), False)])

    df = spark.readStream\
               .option("header", "true")\
               .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")\
               .schema(schema)\
               .csv(constants.input_path)\
               .withColumn("input_file_name", input_file_name())

     df.writeStream\
       .format("delta")\
       .outputMode("append")\
       .option("checkpointLocation", constants.checkpoint_location)\
       .start("/tmp/bronze")

    # await on stream
    sqm = spark.streams
    sqm.awaitAnyTermination()
```

This is using Spark v2.4.4 and Python v3.6.1 and the job is submitted using `spark-submit path/to/job.py`

Comment: This Can Help You
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59170595/how-to-import-delta-lake-module-in-zeppelin-notebook-and-pyspark

Comment: That worked, thanks @TheDarkW3b. I can't believe I missed that question during my search! Submit it as the answer if you like and I'll mark it done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```sh
%pyspark
sc.addPyFile("**LOCATION_OF_DELTA_LAKE_JAR_FILE**")
from delta.tables import *
```